# Swipe events not working on Samsung Galaxy Tab running Android 4.0.4 in Chrome browser

Tags: android, google-chrome, events, swipe

Swipe events are not working at all in mobile web applications running in Chrome on Samsung Galaxy Tab running Android 4.0.4.  Swipe events DO work when running in the standard Android browser, just not in Chrome. What can be done about this?  Is there any workaround to make swipe events work in this environment?